# Show list of not-approved comments in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I have a small website (http://www.effektivkur.dk) and have over 100 articles. Each article have comments that is stored as nodes within Umbraco. This is done to ensure the caching and speed.

However, its becoming an overwhelming task when i need to approve comments, because i need to go to each article in the backoffice and approve the comments. I have no total overview of new comments.

How do i make a list in Umbraco backoffice that displays the not-approved comments, i dont need to be able to approve them in the editor, but a link to the article would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom section where you can list all the comments that are not approved, there's a nice example:
[Recreating the listview in a custom section](http://24days.in/umbraco/2015/custom-listview/)

You also need to create a custom api controller, in the previous link it's called PeopleApiController.
You should use the [Content Service](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/management/services/contentservice) to fetch the comments, something like:

```
var contentService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService;
var root = contentService.GetRootContent().FirstOrDefault(); // this should really be the root of your articles
var commentsNotApproved = root.Descendants().Where(x => x.ContentType.Alias == "Comment" && x.GetValue<bool>("isApproved") == false).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the option outlined by Eyescream, you could also create a custom dashboard that sits in your Content section, just for bulk viewing/approval.

Dashboards are just Angular views, so they're not too fiddly to write. A complete tutorial on how to write a dashboard is probably a bit much to go into here, but if you look at this repo: https://github.com/enkelmedia/TheDashboard it's an example of a reasonably complex dashboard that you could use as a basis for your own code.